# celery ImportError: No module named 'tasks'

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task

I am trying to learn how to use celery to later integrate into my flask app. I am just trying to execute the basic example found on the [Celery Docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#celerytut-troubleshooting) I have created a file called task.py and from within that folder where the file task.py is existing i am running celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info but it is giving an error. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://localhost')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

**error I am seeing**

celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info

ImportError: No module named 'tasks'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing the command from application folder level. If your tasks.py is inside flask_app/configs/tasks.py, then run the following command from inside flask_app folder.

```
celery worker --app=configs.tasks:app --loglevel=info
```

if you want to daemonize celery use following command

```
celery multi start worker --app=configs.tasks:app --loglevel=info
```

** multi start will daemonize the celery,

and be sure to activate virtualenv before running the command, if the application is running inside one.

I am successfully running celery in django with django-celery, had faced the same issue.

Comment: celery multi v4.1.0 (latentcall)
> Starting nodes...
 > worker@myhost: OK